# How to get text content on XPath expression

Tags: xpath, puppeteer

I have like this.

```
var content = await page.$x("//span[@class='property-number']");
```

How to get text content inside that expression?

I already try with this, but not working.

```
var content = await page.evaluate(el => el.innerHTML, await page.$x("//span[@class='property-number']"));
```

Any help are appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try `"//span[@class='property-number']/text()"`